# Linker can't find LIB file of the DLL imported

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, dllimport, dllexport

I've looked through full 14 pages list of similar problems but didn't find my case.

I have VS2017 c++ solution which has two projects DLL and EXE. EXE projects includes DLL header to import function from it.

The problem is that linker can't find `dllproject.lib` file. I tried to add it to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` but didn't help because linker failed to find that lib file and it exists in the output folder.

Then I used

```
#pragma comment( lib, "C:\\FULL_PATH\\dllproject.lib")
```

And this time helped. But the problem is my local absolute path to the lib. I suppose I can somehow configure that in the project settings, but all my attempts failed.

In the DLL header file I have the block (was advised in other answers).

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Please help.

Comment: You may be looking for `Linker > General > Additional Library directories` in project properties.

Comment: Right click the References node of the EXE project > Add Reference > Project > tick your library project.  Done.

Comment: That's the best way, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a library to your project is a two step process.

You add the library name to Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies and you add the library folder to Linker/General/Additional Library Directories.

Then of course you have the potential problem of your program failing to find your DLL, but that's another question.

Comment: Now works as a charm. DLL is in the same folder so it is not a problem. Thanks you!

Comment: Pity there's no Browse button on the error to browse to missing lib files. Maybe they could reassign some developers from the paperclip team to work on it :-
)